# Проблема с подключением расширения jquery (select2)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Вот так подключены файлы скриптов библиотеки *jQuery*:

```
<head>
 ....
    <title></title>
    <script src="/js/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/select2.full.js"></script>
 ....
```

при создании select2 объекта (преобразовании из обычного select в select2) получаю ошибку в консоли

> TypeError: $(...).select2 is not a function

убираешь строку

```
<script src="/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

и ошибка пропадает. Но перестают работать сами UI виджеты (tabs, etc..)

А нужно что бы все работало и UI и Select2

Не могу понять, где причина этого конфликта

PS строки:

```
<script src="/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="/js/select2.full.js"></script>
```

менял местами и не помогло

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В этом [примере](https://jsfiddle.net/HellLena/rd3gL5qc/10/) **jquery-ui** работает совместно с **select2**

Проверьте, точно ли загружается у Вас скрипт **select2.full.js**.

Так же проблема может быть в несовместимости версий. В моём примере используются следующие скрипты:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>
```

В том числе, стили **css** для **jquery-ui** и **select2** так же должны быть обязательно подключены.